# JQuery links to open new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to improve a music player i've created for my website by moving in from in-browser to a separate pop-up window, i've created/manipulated code i've found to make the jQuery take the href value and send it to a new window, only issue is on clicking the `<a>` tag, it performs the href click and jQuery action (as it would do). I'm trying to find an efficient way to make it so that if a user has JavaScript disabled, they can at least use the music player in a new tab rather than not being able to listen at all, but i'm unsure of how to go about this. Would setting the elements href into a var, then removing the href attribute work? Or would this cause errors?

**Example HTML:**

```
<a href="this_page.cfm?song=1" target="_blank" class="playSong" id="#artist# - #song#">Play Track</a>
```

**Example jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".playSong").click(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var windowName = $(this).attr('id');

            window.open(url, windowName, "height=300,width=400");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to prevent default behaviour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".playSong").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the browser to redirect to the href
        // if js is disabled nothing should change and the link will work normally
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var windowName = $(this).attr('id');
        window.open(url, windowName, "height=300,width=400");
    });
});
```

Comment: Which would you say is best to use? `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @LeeB `preventDefault()` is a jQuery only feature. `return false` will do an implicit `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` when used with jQuery so they aren't exactly the same but for this use the behaviour will be the same.

Comment: This one will not play the song if there is a popup blocker

Answer (score 1):

Using a `data-*` attribute would be better than storing song and artist data in the ID.

```
<a href="this_page.cfm?song=1" target="_blank" class="playSong" data-info="#artist# - #song#">Play Track</a>
```

`.preventDefault()` or `return false;` can be used to stop the browser from following the link if Javascript is enabled:

```
$(".playSong").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var windowName = $(this).data('info'); // <-- using .data()

    window.open(url, windowName, "height=300,width=400");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give return false upon clicking the link. As follows :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".playSong").click(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var windowName = $(this).attr('id');

            window.open(url, windowName, "height=300,width=400");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual complete answer to your questions

How to make the link work in a new window if javascript is disabled or a popup blocker is active

```
$(function(){
  $(".playSong").on("click",function(e){
    var w = window.open(this.href, this.target, "height=300,width=400");
    if (w) e.preventDefault(); // prevent link but only if not blocked
  });
});
```